# Sending a single unsigned char through a socket using UDP in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, buffer, sendto

I am trying to send a single `unsigned char` through a buffer. I am using a buffer of size 2

```
unsigned char temp_buf [2];
temp_buf [0]= (unsigned char) 0xff;
temp_buf [1]= NULL;
```

and my `sendto` functions looks like this:

```
if (sendto(fd, temp_buf, sizeof (temp_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
        perror("sendto");
```

It compiles with no issues, however at run time i get an error:

> sendto: Invalid argument

Which means there is something wrong with the buffer im using. I suspected that the issue might be because im using siezeof so i changed it to strlen(temp_buf) but still no luck!

EDIT: I was trying to make the question simpler by not including the whole code but here it is, Sorry about that!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "port.h"

#define BUFSIZE 2048

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;  /* our address */
    struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);        /* length of addresses */
    int recvlen;            /* # bytes received */
    int fd;             /* our socket */
    int msgcnt = 0;         /* count # of messages we received */
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* receive buffer */


    /* create a UDP socket */

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("cannot create socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */

    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVICE_PORT);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }

    /* now loop, receiving data and printing what we received */



        printf("waiting on port %d\n", SERVICE_PORT);

        //recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);

        //buf [0] = 0xff;
        unsigned char temp_buf [2];
        temp_buf [0]= (unsigned char) 0xff;
        temp_buf [1]= '\0';

        if (sendto(fd, temp_buf, sizeof (temp_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
            perror("sendto");
        else
            printf("%s \n", "Communication established");



}
```

Comment: `temp_buf [1]= NULL;` --> `temp_buf [1]= '\0';`

Comment: @AlterMann I already tried that but it didnt work

Comment: How do you populate `remaddr` and `addrlen`?

Comment: Also, how do you create the socket?

Comment: @dbush I added the whole code. Thanks for helping out

Comment: the implicit conversion feature of the compiler is probably handling this for you.  However, a `NULL` is the size of an address pointer (in a 32 bit system that is 4 bytes) but the posted code is trying to assign a single character with a 4 char value.  Strongly suggest using: `'\0'`

Comment: the question has the statement: `#include "port.h"` but no contents for that file.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to raise several warning messages.  Always fix warnings before trying to run.   1) unused variable: `buf[]`.  2) unused parameter: `argc`  3) unused parameter: `argv[]`  4) unused variable: `msgcmt`.  5) unused variable: `recvlen`. When compiling , always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for the `main()` signature, strongly suggest: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `remaddr` are uninitialized.  In other words, you're not telling `sendto` where to send the data.

You need to populate this struct with the IP and port you wish to send to.

If you uncomment the call to `recvfrom` and subsequently get a packet from some other service, `remaddr` gets populated with the IP/port that sent that packet, then you can use that to send a packet back.  But without that, you need to fill in `remaddr`.

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new to UDP socket programming. If my IP is 192.168.1.1 how can i initilize it? Also my port is 8899 which is in another header file called port.h. how can i assign these to remaddr?

Comment: @user3238603 For the IP you can do `remaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");` and `remaddr.sin_port = htons(8889);` for the port

Comment: it worked thanks so much! But one last thing, am i sending the unsigned chars correctly ?

Comment: @user3238603 What you're sending is fine.  As long as the other end knows how to read it, there's no problem.

Comment: im getting 
>sendto: Adress family not supported by protocol
would you happen to know why that might be happening

Comment: @user3238603 You also need to set `remaddr.sin_family = AF_INET`.